# How to make mask collision detection less laggy in python pygame

Tags: python, pygame, mask

Im trying to make a collision detection system for a game im making. This section of code works fine when I am detecting collisions when the objects are smaller, but now once I make a mask of a moon which can be up to 1000 pixels in diameter it starts to lag my computer. Ive tried to make a 2nd image of the outline of the moon to use to detect the collisions but upon further testing it would still detect collisions while in the middle of the outline (in the transparent parts of the image) and did not help the lag. I also tried to make the outline image less pixels but keeping the same size. The images move down the screen as a ship moves across the screen to dodge them. I need pixel perfect collisions
If someone could tell me how to reduce lag, or some other way of detecting if my ship is within the circle that would be a big help :)

```py
for i in range(numMoon):
    moonRect = pygame.Rect(moonX[i], moonY[i], int(100*moonScale[i]), int(100*moonScale[i]))
    if moonRect.colliderect(shipRect):
        moonMask = pygame.mask.from_surface(moon)
        offset_x = shipRect.x - moonRect.x
        offset_y = shipRect.y - moonRect.y
        crash = moonMask.overlap(shipMask, (offset_x, offset_y))
        if crash:
            print('moon')
```

Answer (score 0):

Creating a *Mask* from a *Surface* is an expensive operation. Do not generate the [`pygame.mask`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mask.html) in the loop. Create the mask during initialization directly after loading the image:

```py
moon = pygame.image.load(...)
moonMask = pygame.mask.from_surface(moon)
```

Use the pre-generated mask

```py
for i in range(numMoon):
    moonRect = pygame.Rect(moonX[i], moonY[i], int(100*moonScale[i]), int(100*moonScale[i]))
    if moonRect.colliderect(shipRect):
         offset_x = shipRect.x - moonRect.x
         offset_y = shipRect.y - moonRect.y
         crash = moonMask.overlap(shipMask, (offset_x, offset_y))
         if crash:
             print('moon')
```

Comment: Ok thx this has reduced some of the lag however it still lags a bit when the rect collides it is no longer accurately detecting the if crash:
I forgot to mention that the Y coordinate of the moon will move down the screen, so will that effect the mask?

Comment: @Theo No, the mask is not affected. It might be that the region of intersection is increasing. Mask collision is time consuming. I can't see any further improvement.

Comment: it will print 'moon' whenever the shipRect collides with moonRect now, with a slight bit of lag. When i would create a new mask each time, it would be pixel perfect collisions with a lot lag only when the rect collides. Is there a way of testing a mask collision with a circle to reduce lag, or maybe test to see if a mask if within a certain distance from the centre of the moon?

Comment: @Theo You only have to create a new mask when the `moon` Surface changes! The position of the Surface is irrelevant for the mask. You have a basic misunderstanding.

Comment: @Theo Note, also the `print` call causes a lag